# Custom PHP page form data is not appearing as a wp-theme page template

Tags: php

I have made an age calculator using PHP. It works fine in `localhost/age/age-calculator.php`

I have moved this file as a wp theme-page-template `theme/mytheme/page-template/age-calculator.php`

```
<?php get_header();
/*
Template Name: Age Calculator
*/
```

Create a page and linked with this page-template.

The input forms working nicely but when submit data. WordPress doesn't show me any result and bring me on the home page.

But in localhost, I am getting input result on the same page

How to show the result on the wp page template?

Thanks

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method='post'>
<div class="container bg-light p-2 wow bounceInUp">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-4">
    <p> Your Name * </p>
    <input type="text" name='person_1' placeholder="Name" <?php echo "$required $all_required";?> />
    <p class="text-danger"> <?php echo " $nameErr ";?> </p>
    <br/>

    <p> Date of Birth * </p>
    <input type="date" name='birth_date' <?php echo "$required $all_required";?> /> 
    <p class="text-danger"> <?php echo " $dateErr ";?> </p>
    <br/>

    <input  class="btn-success" type="submit" value='Calculate Yours Age' name='submit_1' /> <br/>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
    <p> Your Friend's Name * </p>
    <input type="text" name='person_2' placeholder= "Friend's Name " <?php echo "$all_required";?> />
    <p class="text-danger"> <?php echo " $nameErr2 ";?> </p>
    <br />

    <p> Your Friend's Date of birth * </p>
    <input type="date" name='birth_date_2' <?php echo "$all_required";?> />
    <p class="text-danger">  <?php echo " $dateErr2 ";?> </p>
    <br /><br />

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input class='m-auto btn btn-success p-2' type="submit" value='Compare Age' name='submit_all' /> 
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: What does your `<form>` tag look like? Does it have a `method` and an `action`?

Comment: <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method='post'>

Comment: To echo Elaine's comment, if you would add the code to your question, you are likely to get a more useful answer.

Comment: @jdm2112 thanks, I have added the form code only. Hole code is more then 400 line

Answer (score 2):

The approach I usually take is to check to see if your submit input exists and construct the page based on that condition.

For example, if your submit/send button was constructed similar to this:

```
<input class="cta" type="submit" name="submit_all" value="Send message">
```

Then your condition check would look like:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submit_all'] ) ) {
    // Do the stuff with $_POST array
} else {
    // No submission yet, show the form
}
```

The key in the $_POST array will match the name attribute of your input.

Elaine's comment is a good one as the action attribute determines where to POST the submission data.  In WordPress, using the permalink is a good option.

```
<form id="####" class="####" method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url( the_permalink() ); ?>">
```

EDIT: based on the code you added to the question, I recommend updating the action attribute on the form element.  Also, I have updated the condition example to use your submit_all value.

Comment: Thanks, @jdm2112     action="<?php echo esc_url( the_permalink() ); ?>"  you help me to solve this problem. :) :)

Comment: Congratulations.  Happy to help.